# How to iterate through dataframe and fill HTML?

Tags: python, html, dataframe

I want to loop through the dataframe below to fill in the HTML file which will populate the last column I only want grade info to fill in if the grade=A.

For example for id =1 the HTML should read:

```
My name is aj. My ID # is 1. 
pass
```

For example for id =2 the HTML should read:

```
My name is bj. My ID # is 2.
```

What I have so far

```
for i in df['grade_info']
    if 'A' in i:
        with open(c:/users/documents/htmlex.txt', 'r') as f:
          template = f.read().strip()
        f.close()
        df['grade_notes']=data.apply(lambda 
        row:template.replace('[Name]',str(row['name']).replace('[ID]',str(row['id']).replace('[GRADE_INFO]',str(row['grade_info']),axis=1)
    else:
         with open(c:/users/documents/htmlex.txt', 'r') as f:
          template = f.read().strip()
        f.close()
        df['grade_notes']=data.apply(lambda 
        row:template.replace('[Name]',str(row['name']).replace('[ID]',str(row['id']).replace('[GRADE_INFO]',' '),axis=1)
```

HTML

```
My name is [NAME]. My ID # is [ID].

[grade_info]
```

Dataframe:

| id | name | grade | grade_info | grade_notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aj | a | pass |  |
| 2 | bj | b | not passsing |  |
| 3 | kj | a | pass |  |
| 4 | mj | c | notpassing |  |
| 5 | dj | f | passing |  |

Comment: Please see code added @esqew

Comment: Can you ensure your code meets the standards of the aforementioned/linked [mre] guidance? For instance, what is `folder`?

Comment: i changed it to my directory.

Answer (score 0):

setting html to an empty list and using .append might be a good place to start

```
intro = 'my name is'
html = []
for name in df[name]:
     html.append(intro)
     html.append(name)

print(html)
out: my name is aj, my name is bj, ...
```